# MySQL Order by value from other table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I've got 2 MySQL-Tables (from the CMS "contenido", if it's known to you):

### **art_lang**

```
idartlang  published (Timestamps)
1          2012-09-20 13:27:47
2          2012-09-21 13:27:47
3          2012-09-12 13:27:47
4          2012-19-22 13:27:47
5          2012-09-25 13:27:47
```

### **content**

```
idartlang  content_type_id content_field_id value
1          2               5                foo
1          9               20               K
2          2               5                bar
3          2               5                foobar
3          9               20               C
4          9               20               Z
```

Now I want to select the Article ID's from Table "art_lang", but ordered by the value of "contents" where content_type_id = 9 AND content_field_id = 2.
And if there is no entry for this Article_ID, order after the other values by art_lang.published...

So that my example would make the following result:

### **Expected Result**

```
art_lang.idartlang  contents.value art_lang.published
3                   C              2012-09-12 13:27:47
1                   K              2012-09-20 13:27:47
4                   Z              2012-09-22 13:27:47
5                                  2012-09-25 13:27:47
2                                  2012-09-21 13:27:47
```

The given query looks like this:

### **Query**

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.idartlang 
FROM art_lang AS a, art AS b, cat_art AS c, content AS cont 
WHERE c.idcat IN ('1374') 
AND b.idart = c.idart 
AND a.idartlang NOT IN ('2233') 
AND b.idclient = '4'
AND a.idlang = '5' 
AND a.idart = b.idart 
AND a.online = 1 
ORDER BY a.published DESC
```

So you see, there are already some dependencies...

Hope you understand what i want :)

Comment: I don't think you can order by a column if its not present in the select list. At least not in MS SQL

Comment: @Rohit You're quite mistaken.

Comment: @user3331882 - Your data set, result set, sample query, and written requirement all differ, which makes the problem rather unclear.

Comment: @Strawberry - Your posted answer has the Order by value in the select list. Where do you think I was wrong?

Comment: @Rohit Error 1: This is MySQL, not MSSQL. Error 2: MSSQL does not require an ORDER BY column to be present within the SELECT list. Error 3: And neither does MySQL.

Comment: @Strawberry - Sorry, I edited my post for all entries to be named the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way...

```
SELECT a.Article_ID
     , c.value 
     , a.published
  FROM art_lang a
  LEFT 
  JOIN contents c
    ON c.article_id = a.article_id
   AND c.content_type_id = 9 
   AND c.content_field_id = 2
 ORDER 
    BY c.value IS NULL, c.value
```